# Saving Bootstrap collapse state between page refresh/page swap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this BS navbar that you can collapse, and I want it to save the state when I change page or refresh the current page.

**home.php**

```
<!-- Side Navbar -->
<nav class="side-navbar">
  <div class="side-navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidenav-header d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div class="sidenav-header-inner text-center"><img src="img/marcus_avatar.png" alt="person" class="img-fluid rounded-circle">
        <h2 class="h5 text-uppercase"><?php echo $_COOKIE['userName']; ?></h2><span class="text-uppercase">Web Admin</span>
      </div>
      <div class="sidenav-header-logo"><a href="home" class="brand-small text-center"> <strong>S</strong><strong class="text-primary">F</strong></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-menu">
      <ul id="side-main-menu" class="side-menu list-unstyled">                  
        <li class="active"><a href="home"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li> <a href="users"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span>Users</span></a></li>
        <li> <a href="upload"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i><span>Upload</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="files"><i class="fa fa-file"></i><span>My Files</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**jsfile.js**

```js
$(".side-navbar").on('shown.bs.collapse', function ()
{
    var active = $(this).attr('id');
    $.cookie(active, "1");
});

$(".side-navbar").on('hidden.bs.collapse', function ()
{
    var active = $(this).attr('id');
    $.removeCookie(active);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var panels=$.cookie(); //get all cookies
    for (var panel in panels){ //<-- panel is the name of the cookie
        if ($("#"+panel).hasClass('shrink')) // check if this is a panel
        {
            $("#"+panel).collapse("show");
        }
    }    
});
```

I want it to work like this: http://jsfiddle.net/03u0bfst/3/ but I just can't get it to work for the life of me!

Comment: Adding a note here that I forgot: when the navbar is "collapsed" it adds a class called shrink so the class becomes: side-navbar shrink

Comment: the fiddle which you provided is working as per your requirement..then what else is expected ?

Comment: @Krishna9960 I'll show you what I mean with 2 pictures. First picture is the default state.
1. https://i.imgur.com/LtzG1GZ.png

Second picture is when I click the collapse button, it adds a class on the navbar called "shrink", basically just reducing the width of the navbar:

2. https://i.imgur.com/L4NYThb.png

so I want the current state to always be saved, which is what the user recently was shown.

Comment: see for current session you can do it with the help of local storage...but if you want it to be remembered for every login irrespective of his location then you have to maintain it in the database.

For current session local storage should help u.

Comment: Thanks. I just need to understand now how I can add/delete a class to a div now with a button click. Should be possible with localStorage I guess?

Comment: Yes to maintain the state local storage will be helpful.